# How to define custom css for Jquery UI button

Tags: css, asp.net

I am using JQuery UI button on different pages and trying to remove corners on certain pages.

I have defined the following css which works fine but it effects other buttons on other pages. I am only using one style sheet for all web pages.

Is it possible if it can effect only those buttons which are defined inside the cssbox table?

```
 <table class="cssbox" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="398px" style="height: 287px;margin:0 auto;">
    <tr><td>
    <asp:Button ID="btnLogin"  Text=" Login " runat="server" CssClass="ui-corner-all ui-corner-all hover"  />

   </td> </tr>
 </table>

.cssbox ui-corner-all { 
width:265px;
border-radius: 0px; 
background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% #1A7BC9;
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #1A7BC9 0px, #1A7BC9 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0,startColorstr='#1A7BC9', endColorstr='#1A7BC9');/*For IE7-8-9*/ 
border: 1px solid #1A7BC9;
height: 35px;
font-size: 12px;
}

.cssbox ui-corner-all:hover { 
border-radius: 0px; 
background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% #9CC8F7;
color: #404040;
border: 1px solid #9CC8F7;
filter: none;
}
```

Or can it be done in jquery function as I am using following function on certain pages for adding custom icon on jquery UI button. There is a remove and add function with jquery but would it work for class "cssbox"? I don't want to create separate jquery functions for different pages.

```
$(function () {
$("input:submit").button({
    icons: { primary: 'cssbox-okbtn' }
}).hide().after('<button>').next().button({
    icons:
    {
        primary: 'cssbox-okbtn'
    },
    label: $("input:submit").val()
}).click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).prev().click();
});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

In the pages you want to remove specific style of jquery ui, apply "removeCorners" class to the button elements:

```
$('button').addClass('removeCorners');
```

CSS

```
.removeCorners {
    /* your custom style */
}
```

Comment: do i need to give button id $('mybutton')? all buttons have different names. Can i use $("input:submit").button.addClass('removeCorners');

Comment: You can use $('input[type=submit]').addClass('removeCorners');